# Binary to Decimal Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, binary, numbers

This code is supposed to take in a string ("100101") and output the result in decimal.I'm not quite sure why it's not working.Any help would be appreciated.

```
function BinaryConverter(str) { 
 var num=str.split("");
 var powers=[];
 var sum=0;
  for(var i=0;i<num.length;i++){
   powers.push(i);
}
 for(var i=powers.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  for(var j=0;j<num.length;i++){
   sum+=Math.pow(2,i)*num[j];
  }
 }
 return sum;
};
```

Here's my updated code below .For an input "011" it should do( 2^2*0 +2^1*1 +2^0*1)to =3 but it returns 14.Anybody know where I'm going wrong?

```
    function BinaryConverter(str) { 
     var num=str.split("");
     var powers=[];
     var sum=0;
     for(var i=0;i<num.length;i++){
       powers.push(i);
     }
     for(var i=powers.length-1;i>=0;i--){
      for(var j=0;j<num.length;j++){
       sum+=Math.pow(2,i)*num[j];
      }
     }
     return sum;
    };
```

Comment: why don't you just use parseInt with a different radix?
es:
var a = parseInt("01001011", 2);

Comment: You've got `i++` in the inner loop instead of `j++`. You can do this without calling `Math.pow()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two nested for loops have a problem. The first one subtracts an i, while the second adds an i forever creating a never ending loop.

ALSO your code should be this:

```
    function BinaryConverter(str) { 
        var num=str.split("");
        var powers=[];
        var sum=0;
        var numlength=num.length;

        for(var i=0;i<num.length;i++){
            powers.push(i);
        }

        for(var i=powers.length-1;i>=0;i--){

            sum+=Math.pow(2,i)*num[numlength-i-1];

        }
        return sum;
   };
```

I don't think you need the nested for loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this returns the wrong answer Input "011" should give 3 but instead it gives 6

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do that with `parseInt()` for some reason (like, because the homework problem says you can't), you can do this without the complexity and expense of calling `Math.pow()` for each digit:

```
function parseBinary(str) {
  var i, value = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
    value = value * 2 + +str[i];
  return value;
}
```

That doesn't check for invalid input strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.What is the effect of adding a comma at   var i,value=0;

Comment: @mkmkmk4 that just separates separate variables being declared in the `var` statement. That statement declares `i` and `value`. Only `value` is initialized (to `0`); `i` will be `undefined` but that's OK because the `for` loop initializes it.

Answer (score 0):

ace040686 only inverted the `pow(2,i)` and `num[len-1-i]` in his answer, otherwise it would be correct. Also you're pushing 0..str.length-1 unnecessarily to `powers`, those are implicit indices.

```
function convertNaive(str) {
  var num = str.split("");
  var len = num.length;
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    sum += Math.pow(2, len - 1 - i) * num[i];
  return sum;
}
```

You can improve this a bit to avoid the unnecessary array and especially `Math.pow`:

```
function convertImproved(str) {
  var len = str.length;
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0, fac = 1; i < len; ++i, fac *= 2)
    sum += fac * str[len - 1 - i];
  return sum;
}
```

Try it yourself:

```js
var input = "100101";
var logNode = document.getElementById("log");

function log(line) {
  var text = document.createTextNode(line);
  var node = document.createElement("p");
  node.appendChild(text);
  logNode.appendChild(node);
}

function convertNaive(str) {
  var num = str.split("");
  var len = num.length;
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    sum += Math.pow(2, len - 1 - i) * num[i];
  return sum;
}

function convertImproved(str) {
  var len = str.length;
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0, fac = 1; i < len; ++i, fac *= 2)
    sum += fac * str[len - 1 - i];
  return sum;
}

log("input: " + input);
log("parseInt(input, 2): " + parseInt(input, 2));
log("convertNaive(input): " + convertNaive(input));
log("convertImproved(input): " + convertImproved(input));
```

```html
<div id="log" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple implementation of binary to decimal in javascript.

```
main();

function main() {
    let binaryInput = 10000100111;
    let decimalOutput = binaryTodecimal(binaryInput);
    console.log(decimalOutput);
}

function binaryTodecimal(input) {
    let inputString = input.toString();
    let result = 0;
    let exponent = 1;
    let currentBit = 0;
    for (let i = inputString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentBit = parseInt(inputString[i]);
        currentBit *= exponent;
        result += currentBit;
        exponent *= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```